# itext, pdf size A4, and image scalling

Tags: java, itext, scale

My paper its B4 - 17,60cm x 24,50cm

its scanned have the size in pixels -> 2048 x 2929

im creating a PDF as A4 size (2480px x 3508px) using itext.. but im unable to scale it with margins, and not even without margins, i need to insert the B4 image into the PDF A4 size, using LEFT margin of 2,5cm and the RIGH margin 2cm, but how can i make it fit calculating the sizes, since a paper A4 has 2480x3508, the B4 image has 2048x2929, if i insert, it cut? the b4 is bigger :| how?? considering size of A4, and the b4 should fit perfectly inside the A4

if i do this:

```
doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
os = new FileOutputStream(arquivonomecompleto);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, os);
        doc.open();
       Image img = Image.getInstance(arraypath[i]); // the array store the path to the image    
      //  img.scaleToFit(2090, 1208); // i tried a lot of modifications, i can set i to 500x500 or something like this in have all showed in the pdf, but how can i calculate margins


           doc.add(img);
               doc.add(new Paragraph("TEST: text under the b4 image");
           doc.newPage();
```

still cutting

if i convert the 17cm and 29,70cm to pixels, and set it in the img.setScaleToFit, still cutting, how? or my computer is crazy or the PDF A4 Size of ITEXT is wrong :|

look what i want:

[image]

edit: ops, the margin of LEFT side is 2cm too :)

Comment: I don't understand the question (and I think you don't get an answer because other people are confused to). You're talking about pixels, but PDF works with user units that (by default) correspond with points. An A4 page measures 595 by 842 user units. Knowing that, why are you talking about 2480px x 3508px? Can you replace the px measurements with user units in your question? That way, your question will be easier to understand.